# Why do I get nextElementSibling is not a function?

Tags: javascript

please see here:

Basically, I'm trying what should be the es6 version of jquery's `next()` dom utility. It doesn't work. Why? Given this example, and succefully referenced the button, `button.nextElementSibling()` will throw an error saying `nextElementSibling` is not a function. Why?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  const b = document.querySelector('.b');
  console.log(b.nextElementSibling());  
});
```

```html
<button class="b">button</button>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Comment: ```nextElementSibling``` isn't a function.  It's a property. (got this from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) is not a function, it is a property

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  const b = document.querySelector('.b');
  // I removed the ()
  console.log(b.nextElementSibling);  
});
```

```html
<button class="b">button</button>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> [...] error saying `nextElementSibling` is not a function. Why?

It says it's not a function because it's not a function! It's an `Element`.

You can check that: The logical next question after seeing the error should be "if it's not a function, then what is it?" which can be answered by logging it without attempting to call it or inspecting its value in the debugger.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling):

> The `Element.nextElementSibling` read-only **property** returns the element immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list, or `null` if the specified element is the last one in the list.
>
> ##### Value
>
> **A `Element` object**, or `null`.

(Emphasis mine.)

So, don't call it:

```js
console.log(b.nextElementSibling)
```